# Finding most recent inserted document for a mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Currently, this is my code in order to find the most recent document in my mongodb database

```
    async def _last_bump_time(self):
        last_bump = bump_db.find().limit(1).sort('$natural', ASCENDING).limit(1)
        last_bump = last_bump["date"]
        return datetime.strptime(last_bump,"%S:%M:%H:%d:%m:%Y")
```

but it is giving me an error, `TypeError: index 'date' cannot be applied to Cursor instances`
What is the best way to find the most react document, and be able to retrieve the data from the document without having the document to have an extra parameter?
'
My document is ordered like this with three parameters

```
_id:6292a0d4cc2ef69845749028
id:736933464292589568
date:"16:23:20:28:05:2022"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`find`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) which is intended to retrieve multiple documents. It returns a [Cursor](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor), which lets you go through the returned documents one-by-one.

You could instead use [`find_one`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one), which will return a single document or `None`. `find_one` also supports passing a `sort` parameter, expecting a list of (key, direction) pairs specifying the sort order. Put all together, it could look like this:

```py
async def _last_bump_time(self):
    last_bump = bump_db.find_one(sort=[('$natural', DESCENDING)])
    # last_bump is None if your database is empty.
    if last_bump:
        return datetime.strptime(last_bump["date"],"%S:%M:%H:%d:%m:%Y")
    return datetime.now() # Example return value in the case of an empty database. Feel free to update.
```

Comment: With `find_one(sort=[('$natural', ASCENDING)])`, will this return the newest or oldest doc?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I believe you're right, this would return the oldest doc. I overlooked that when adapting the original code.

Comment: So if i want the newest doc, it should be `.find_one(sort=[('$natural', DSCENDING)])`?

Comment: @bensonchow Yes.